# Does HTTP stub server stubby4j support request proxying with additional query params setting?

Tags: microservices, integration-testing, web-api-testing, mockserver, stubby4j

**TL;DR**:

Does stubby4j request proxying functionality support the setting of additional query params with the request which is being proxied?

**Details**:

I am using stubby4j HTTP stub server, the latest version (i.e.: `v7.3.3`) to proxy requests to another real live service when my request did not match any of the configured stubs.

I am interested to know if it is possible to pass in additional query params to the live service with the request which is being proxied?

In the official docs of the [stubby4j](https://stubby4j.com) request proxying behavior (https://stubby4j.com/docs/request_proxying.html) there is nothing mentioned about it and from what I see in my own testing, I do not think this is supported. But, I still wanted to ask on SO to check if I am simply doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the the setting of additional query params on the request being proxied is not supported currently.

As per the aforementioned docs, the `additive` strategy only supports the setting of additional HTTP headers, which are specified in the `headers` property on the `proxy-config` object in your YAML.

But, it is pretty straightforward to add the addition of query params behavior. Feel free to raise a feature request at https://github.com/azagniotov/stubby4j/issues/new/choose